# Ignored user in chat messes up user list

Tags: bug, chat, design

When an ignored user joins a chat room, their avatar is shown in half size in the user list to the top right. The container that contains the avatar retains its full height, so everything is pushed down by half an avatar's height on my screen when an ignored user joins.

[image: A wild ignored user appears. 16 pixels extra room under the avatar.]

More specifically, the `ignored` class seems to be added on the user container. It resizes the avatar, but the height of the container is governed by `#present-users > .present-user, #present-users .more`, which makes the height 32 pixels. I believe `.present-user.ignored` should set the `height` to `16px` to match `.ignored .user-gravatar32`.